# How to target bootstrap tab when click on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link in my home page to go to edit profile page. In editing page I have used bootstrap tabs like below,

```
<ul class="nav custom-nav">
  <li role="presentation" >
    <a href="#restaurant-basic-info" aria-controls="restaurant-basic-info" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Restaurant Info</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#edit-cuisine" aria-controls="edit-cuisine" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cuisine</a>
  </li></ul>
</ul>
```

Tab Contents:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <!-- Tab pane-1 -->
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="restaurant-basic-info">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="crearfix"></div>

      <div class="form-footer">
        <div class="action ">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
          <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </form>  
  </div>

  ......

</div>
```

So. Now I want to open the tab with the ID of `restaurant-basic-info`, when click on the link from home page.

Is it possible to do? I found similar question here but none of them not help me to this scenario.

Hope Somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Where is the tab with id `restaurant-basic-info`?

Comment: @AbraarArique, updated the question..

Comment: have you tried passing `#restaurant-basic-info` in URL?

Comment: Yes.. I tried it but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: @user3733831 It should work if you create the URL like: `<a href="edit_profile.php#restaurant-basic-info"> Edit Profile </a>`.

Comment: @AbraarArique, I have already checked it before ask this. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the tab by calling this:

```
$('ul.custom-nav a[href="#restaurant-basic-info"]').tab('show');
```

This can be executed on page load. Please check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marianc/Lcp18jns/)

Comment: Can you tell me is it possible to activate the tab when click on this link `<a href="edit_profile.php">Edit Profile</a>` which is placed on different page

Comment: Yes. The activation code is at the bottom of the html section and it runs on page load.